# Ho to make a Comvisible C# WinForms Control Library (ActiveX)

Tags: c#, winforms, activex

Bear with me, I have less than an on/off relationship with VS and C#, but last time I created something COM visible it was simply a tick in the assembly info of a project.

In a VS2022 WinForm Control Library I don't see that option. Maybe as I picked .NET framework 6.

A concrete idea I would like to do with this is have a COM wrapper to the Microsoft WebView2  with modern JS support to be used in a legacy project that can make use of ActiveX controls. (Instead of cefSharp, I'm aware of that project and also some commercial options like WebKit ActiveX).

Is it perhaps thinkable to even create a general wrapper like an ActiveX container for dotNet (WinForms) controls? so dotNet UI can be shared in legacy projects?

Way back in 2010 there was an interop toolkit that could do such things, but again, I think it was quite doable without its help by the interop option of COM visibility of assemblies.

Should I (again) revert to an older Studio version? I would like to avoid multiple installs. Since I found ways to extend project types, is there a way to get legacy (classic) project types into VS 2022 to achieve something like that?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Comment: The checkbox generated a class interface. The link Stefan provided details an arguably better way to expose a managed component to COM.

Comment: Thanks for the comment answer. Better make it an answer, perhaps? I don't know, but as far as I am used to StackOverflow from reading, then the best answer can get votes and flows or stays at the top. I still have to give it a try.

Comment: @LegacyDev, I am also not sure, especially believing I read somewhere SO would consider so-called link-only answers to be a real bad thing

Comment: Did it work? A COM exposed library is not the same as an AX control